# creating a icon button that has a selector xml file as background

Tags: android, button, android-imagebutton

I am trying to make a icon button that when the user clicks on it, as a click effect, the color of the icon changes. for this, i tried a selector xml file that select different png files, this is a simple selector code that I thaught it would work, but there must be something that I am missing, the xml file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/continue_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/continue_not_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

however when I try to run the app on emulator, it crashes! and there is nothing in log so i can tell what the problem is. but when i try just one png file for the background of the button it works!
the xml code for the button looks like this:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/about_icon1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_continue"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.5" />
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector only has state_pressed true and false (this can't be used) and it doesn't have a default one. Try do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

And in the xml where you set your Button layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/about_icon1"
        android:background="@drawable/your_selector_xml_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.5" />
```

Notice you should put the selector code above in another xml file and that xml file should be in your drawable directory. So that when you set the background for your Button it will use the selector xml file to be your Button's 'background'.

Comment: I updated my code accordingly, but again same problem continued !